# bash shell script, issues with a 32 bit decimal to binary converter

Tags: bash, shell, math, binary, decimal

Having an issue with this
when I run it, the console repeats this over and over;

```
14: shellscript.sh: 2: not found
15: shellscript.sh: 32: not found
18: shellscript.sh: =1: not found
19: shellscript.sh: 0: not found
```

It seems like it's something to do with how bash handles redefining variables through arithmetic?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This script converts a user's number into an IP address."
echo -n "Input your number: "
read user

if [ $user -lt 4294967296 ]
then
  exp=$((32))
  num=$((0))
  ipb=""
  while [ $exp -gt 0 ]
  do
    bit=expr 2 ** $exp
    exp=expr $exp - 1
    if [ $bit+$num -le $user ]
    then
      $ipb="${ipb}1"
      num=expr $num + $bit
    else
      $ipb="${ipb}0"
fi
done
echo $ipb
echo "done"
fi
```

Same as above but with comments to explain it.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This script converts a user's number into an IP address."
echo -n "Input your number: "
read user

#check if number is larger than 32bits
if [ $user < 4294967296 ]
then
#var exp is exponent that will be used to redefine var bit each loop cycle
#var num is var used to rebuild the user number with corresponding bits added to -
#var ipb is IP binary (not yet converted to 4 octet integers)
  exp=$((32))
  num=$((0))
  ipb=""
#while the exponent is greater than 0 (exponent is 1 less as per binary order)
  while [ $exp > 0 ]
  do
#(Re)define bit var for line 23
    bit=expr 2**$exp
#go to next lowest exponent
    exp=expr $exp - 1
#If the current bit is added to our num var,will it be 
#less than or equal to the user number?
    if [ $bit + $num -le $user ]
    then
#If so, redefine the ipb string var with a 1 on the end
#and redefine the num integer var added with the current 
#iteration of the bit integer var's value
      $ipb="${ipb}1"
      num=expr $num + $bit
    else
#if not, redefine the ipb string var with a 0 on the end
      $ipb="${ipb}0"
fi
done
#output the IP binary
echo $ipb
echo "done"
fi
```

**EDIT:
After some googling and help from shellcheck I got it to work. for some reason with my version of linux mint, the `let` command was the only thing that correctly took `2**31` as an exponent operation. Here's the code for anyone curious.**

```
echo "This script converts a user's number into the 32 bit equivalent."
echo -n "Input a number below 4294967296: "
read user
echo ""
if [ $user -lt 4294967296 ]
then
  exp=$((31)) 
  num=$((0)) 
  ipb=""
  while [ $exp -ge 0 ]
  do
    let bit=2**$exp
    let exp-=1
    if (( $bit + $num <= $user ))
      then
        ipb="${ipb}1"
        num=$(($num + $bit))
      else
        ipb="${ipb}0"
    fi
  done
fi
echo $ipb
```

Be sure to use `bash` instead of `sh` or `./` when running the script in terminal.

Comment: please try to modify your script with suggestions from http://www.shellcheck.net/ and then see if problem persists..

Comment: `if [ $bit + $num -le $user ]` So you know that the number comparison is to be done with `-le / -ge` (though the if condition itself is still wrong...) & you still used `while [ $exp > 0 ]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your script has several issues. This one does not throw any errors.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "This script converts a user's number into an IP address."
echo -n "Input your number: "
read user

if [ $user -lt 4294967296 ]
then
  exp=$((32))
  num=$((0))
  ipb=""
  while [ $exp -gt 0 ]
  do
    bit=$((2 ** $exp))
    exp=$(expr $exp - 1)
    if (( bit+num  < user ))
    then
      ipb="${ipb}1"
      num=$(expr $num + $bit)
    else
      ipb="${ipb}0"
fi
done
echo $ipb
echo "done"
fi
```

One major issue is that `expr` cannot calculate powers. You also do not use command substitution when you are trying to assign the result of `expr` to a variable.
Another major issue is that you cannot do math inside single `[ ]` brackets as you try to do in an if branch. Use `(( ))` instead.
There were a few other issue, e.g., `$ipb="${ipb}1"` expanding the variable that you actually want to assign.